# C# How to bind WPF GeometryModel3D to ViewModel with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d, caliburn.micro

I am trying to bind a GeometryModel3D from my XAML to a property of a property in my ViewModel in C#. I am using Caliburn.Micro to establish my MVVM. Below is a simplified snippet of how I am trying to bind in my View XAML:

```
<Viewport3D>
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <Model3DGroup>
                <GeometryModel3D x:Name = "CubeVisual_Cube">
            </Model3DGroup>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

and in my C# ViewModel:

```
private CubeModel _cubeVisual = new CubeModel();
public CubeModel CubeVisual
{
    get { return _cubeVisual; }
    set
    {
        _cubeVisual = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CubeVisual);
    }
}
```

CubeVisual has a constructor that fully establishes the geometry and material of the GeomretyModel3D. And finally the piece of my CubeModel class that creates the GeometryModel3D property:

```
public class CubeModel
{
    private GeometryModel3D _cube;
    public GeometryModel3D Cube
    {
        get { return _cube; }
        set { _cube = value; }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, it doesn't seem the cube properly binds to the Geometry3D in my View. No breakpoints are hit inside my CubeVisual property. There are no errors being generated to help me figure this out. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you do it without `Caliburn.Micro` getting in the way? If you can't, then try THAT first. If there are any binding issues, then VS **Output** window will tell you about it.

Comment: I am considering dropping my MVVM so I can bind with the xaml.cs file. It might be worth it in my situation since I am the only dev and this is a small project.

Comment: You can and should have [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) without caliburn micro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewport3D doesn't support data binding, so you're not going to get this to work even with regular INPC let alone Caliburn Micro. It's incredibly annoying, if you ask me, because there's no good reason why this should be any different than it is for 2D i.e. you should be able to use Viewport3D as an ItemsControl panel and then use data templates to populate the scene with graphics objects based on the collection of scene view models (if it couldn't be implemented like this exactly then it should have at least been something similar). Alas, none of this has been incorporated into the 3d classes, so we're left with this hodge-podge of semi-support where individual 3d object properties are proper dependency properties with full binding support etc but the actual scene management itself isn't.

So basically if you want this you have to do it yourself. Create a user control with an "ItemsSource" dependency property and then set up collection change notification so that when the items in this list change you update your scene accordingly. How you map view models to the actual 3d scene objects is up to you, one possible solution is to use the view model as the key to the 3d object you want it to represent (it's worth noting that this is actually how DataTemplates work in the 2D case....`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelType}>` is just syntactic sugar for `<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type viewModelType}>`).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Definitely a different way of doing it but I will give it a shot.